# Prevent Angular creating Value attribute on Option using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I'm using Angular to create a select element with options:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" 
    ng-options="myListItem.name as myListItem.name for myListItem in myList">
</select>
```

For the data:

```
$scope.myList = [
    { name: "option one" },
    { name: "option two" }
];
$scope.mySelectedValue = null;
```

This renders:

```
<select ...>
    <option value='0'>option one</option>
    <option value='1'>option two</option>
</select>
```

The value attribute can be changed to duplicate the option text using `track by myListItem.name, rendering:

```
<select>
    <option value='option one'>option one</option>
    <option value='option two'>option two</option>
</select>
```

But, there appears to be no way in Angular to prevent the value attribute being added to the options. ie: The following is valid HTML but cannot be rendered using Angular ng-options (as far as I can tell) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option?#attr-value

```
<select>
    <option>option one</option>
    <option>option two</option>
</select>
```

Using an ng-repeat on the options is apparently not recommended due to issues on IE - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2809

Is this a limitation of Angular?

Comment: I believe angular uses the `value` attribute to track the different items. Have you looked at the source?

Comment: The source of Angular? No I haven't... good idea